# Prevent vim from jumping through source code

Tags: vim

folks!

I'm using vim as an IDE for writing code in bash, Python and C. Besides, I have a key map to execute my current buffer depending on the file type. Here is a responsible parts of my .vimrc:

```
...
autocmd FileType python call Python_source()
autocmd FileType sh call Bash_source()
...
" Read lw (lispwords) modelise from current buffer and pass it as command arguments
func! LWargs()
    set lw=''
    doautocmd BufRead
    if len(&lw) > 0 && len(&lw) < 512
        return ' ' . &lw
    endif
    return ''
endfunc

func! Python_source()
    setlocal number cursorline
    setlocal shiftwidth=2
    setlocal foldmethod=indent

    map <F9> :w \| :exe '!python' '%:p' . LWargs()<CR>
    imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :exe '!python' '%:p' . LWargs()<CR>

    " Comments on Ctrl-C
    map <C-C> :call ToggleComment('#')<CR>
    imap <C-C> <Esc>:call ToggleComment('#')<CR>li
endfunc

func! Bash_source()
    setlocal number cursorline
    setlocal shiftwidth=4

    map <F9> :w \| :!./%<CR>
    imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :!./%<CR>

    map <C-C> :call ToggleComment('#')<CR>
    imap <C-C> <Esc>:call ToggleComment('#')<CR>li
endfunc
...
```

So, when I press F9, the magic happen and my code is executed with arguments passed by the LWargs. The only problem is after the program exits, vim will jump to the beginning of the file forcing me to position cursor back the line I was working and making my life harder. Is there is any way to prevent vim from jumping around?

Comment: for a quick hack-fix, you can probably make use of markers.  what happens if you do `\`\`` after wards to jump back to your previous location?  If that doesn't work, can you set a mark at the start and jump back to it at the end?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm using markers to circumvent this for years and I tired of doing this.

Comment: Can you not add the markers to your F9 maps to automate it?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I use manual markers and add them during code editing and before hitting F9.

Comment: Right.  But what if instead you added `\`\`` after `<CR>` in your maps?  Would that jump you back to where you were?  Or if it requires a manual marker to be set, do that as the first thing in your map.

Comment: Other than my answer, you might want to consider: 1) Make the mappings non-recursive, use `:nnoremap` and `:inoremap`. Prefer `:nnoremap` over `:noremap`, if you want to include Visual mode too, make sure you include `:<C-U>` after the `:` otherwise the command will likely fail. 2) Make your mappings local to the buffer, otherwise if you load a Python file, then a shell file, the mappings will no longer work in the Python file, use `:nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :w \| !./%<CR>`. Also note you don't need an extra `:` after a `\|`, it's already expecting an Ex command after the `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `doautocmd BufRead` command in your `LWargs()`, which resets the cursor position to the top of the file.

(At least in my case, the command used to [restore cursor position upon opening Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/defaults.vim#L114-L121) is the one causing the cursor to move. You can inspect the list from `:autocmd BufEnter *` to see if you can spot a similar command or another one that might be causing the cursor to move. Looking again, it turns out I was *also* getting that same rule from my Linux distribution...)

A good way to prevent this is to use [`winsaveview()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winsaveview%28%29) to save the cursor location and the window view in general (which line is at the top, whether your window is scrolled right to a column when word wrap is off) and [`winrestview()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winrestview%28%29) to restore it.

Here's an updated `LWargs()` that won't move your cursor:

```
function! LWargs()
    set lw=
    let saved_view = winsaveview()
    doautocmd BufRead
    call winrestview(saved_view)
    if len(&lw) > 0 && len(&lw) < 512
        return ' ' . &lw
    endif
    return ''
endfunction
```

Note also that the correct syntax is `set lw=`, if you use `set lw=''` you'll be setting a two-character string with two single quotes.

Comment: The `winsaveview()` did the job just perfect. Besides, I updated my LispWords as you suggested. Thank you.